# Замена слов в цикле

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте. Есть массив со словами которые нужно заменить. И есть текст в который нужно заменить на слова из массива.
Вот мой код

```
$data = //берется из бд текст
$Arr = Array();
$Arr[]="Классы";
$Arr[]="Ученики";
$Arr[]="Книги";
for($i = 0; $i < count($Arr); ++$i) {
    $data = str_replace($Arr[$i],"<i>".$Arr[$i]."</i><br>",$data);
 }
print $data;
```

Comment: и что с ним не так?

Comment: не заменяет текст

Comment: данные выводит, но без замены

Comment: заменяет - https://eval.in/577605

Comment: Может ли быть дело в кодировке?

Comment: Да может. И, видимо, скорее всего

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код правильный. Проблема была в кодировке файла.